# Why can't I sum values ​for a given period with intervals present in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a software. I can not change the model.

The software is a film rental manager.

In the database, I have some clients and differents type of rental and different type of client (free, vip, vip+, ...)

A client can rent a movie for one day, one week, buy a movie, etc. He starts as a free client and if he pay, he can get VIP or VIP+ offer.

Inside this table (Rent), I have the information about a rent. I know which type of rent it is (10 is for rent only for one day), the date and the duration of the movie rental.

| owner_id | Type | Date | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| POA | 10 | 2021-01-28 | 8 |
| POA | 10 | 2021-06-29 | 7.30 |

`POA` is the `owner_id`. It's a natural id. It comes from my `client` table :

| id | c_id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | POA | Paul |

And I have a table that contains all the offer's history for one client.

| user_cid | group | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| poa | free | 2000-01-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| poa | VIP | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-30 |
| poa | VIP+ | 2021-07-01 | 2099-12-31 |

`2000-01-01` and `2099-12-31` are default value given by the software. I can't change them.

`2000-01-01` is the default value when a user is created and `2099-12-31` means that this offer is the current client's offer.

In this case, Paul was a free member from the day he created his account to the `2021-04-30` and then he became a VIP member from the `2021-05-01` to the `2021-06-30`. After this, he subscribed to a VIP+ offer from the `2021-07-01` and it's still his current offer to this day.

Now what I'm trying to do, is to display a history of films rented by Paul in a given period. But I would like to separate the history by group.

Per example If I give a period from `2021-01-01` to `2021-06-30`, a desired input would be this :

| Name | Group | Rent (1 day) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | free | 8 |
| Paul | VIP | 7.30 |

I can see the total duration of the `type 10` rentals (which is one-day rental) for each group. When Paul was a free user he rented films for 8 hours and when he was a VIP user he rented for 7.30 hours (as we can see in the first and the third table).

So I tried this :

```
SELECT p.name, h.group, sum(caase when r.type = '10' then r.hours else 0 end) 

FROM client p 
left outer join history h
 on h.user_cid = p.c_id
join rent r 
 on r.owner_id = p.c_id
and r.date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-06-30'

where p.c_id = 'poa'

group by p.name
```

With this request I have this result (it sums all the hours and not by group) :

| Name | Group | Rent (1 day) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | free | 15.30 |
| Paul | VIP | 15.30 |

So I don't know how to handle the history date.

I have to handle it like this :

If the start period is `2021-01-01` and the end period is `2021-06-30` then sum the duration from the start period to the end of the free offer `2021-04-30` and then in an other row sum the duration from the start of the vip offer `2021-05-01` to the end period. (And repeat this pattern if the member changed his subscription more than 2 time).

Finally, I have to handle the default date `2000-01-01` and `2099-12-31` too. I thought about doing something like this :

```
caase when from '2000-01-01' then `2021-01-01` else r.date end
```

PS :

Why can't I  post my question when I write 'case' inside a code block ? I had to write it with two 'a' to post it.

**UPDATE**

Result of ekochergin's soluion :

| Name | Group | Rent (1 day) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | free | 7.30 |
| Paul | VIP | 0 |

It didn't sum correctly. `7.30` is supposed to be in the VIP group and VIP is 0 (the result should be `7.30'`).

**UPDATE 2**

So here is my full table :

| user_cid | item_id | type | group | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| poa | c_gr1 | group | free | 2000-01-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| poa | c_gr2 | group | VIP | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-30 |
| poa | c_gr3 | group | VIP+ | 2021-07-01 | 2099-12-31 |
| poa | c_tp1 | plateform | android | 2000-01-01 | 2021-02-03 |
| poa | c_tp2 | plateform | webos | 2021-02-04 | 2099-12-31 |
| poa | c_cntry1 | country | uk | 2000-01-01 | 2021-03-01 |
| poa | c_cntry2 | country | usa | 2021-03-02 | 2099-12-31 |

For each type I have a table that display some basics information

| group_id | offer | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c_grp1 | free | 0 |
| c_grp2 | VIP | 5 |
| c_grp3 | VIP+ | 10 |

| plateform_id | name | brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c_tp1 | android | google |
| c_tp2 | webos | LG |

| country_id | name | capital_city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c_cntry1 | uk | London |
| c_cntry2 | USA | Washington |

Here is my request :

```
SELECT p.name, grp.name, sum(caase when r.type = '10' then r.hours else 0 end) 

FROM client p 
left outer join userHistory ch
 on ch.user_cid = p.c_id
join country ctry
 on ctry.country_id = ch.item_id
and ch.type='country'
and ch.fto >='2021-01-01' and ch.from <='2021-06-30'

left outer join userHistory ph
 on ph.user_cid = p.c_id
join plateform pl
 on pl.plateform_id = ph.item_id
and ph.type='plateform'
and ph.to >='2021-01-01' and ph.from <='2021-06-30'

left outer join userHistory gh
 on gh.user_cid = p.c_id
join group g
 on g.plateform_id = gh.item_id
and gh.type='group'
and gh.to >='2021-01-01' and gh.from <='2021-06-30'

join rent r 
 on r.owner_id = p.c_id
   and r.date between gh.date_from and gh.date_to
 where p.c_id = 'poa'
   and r.date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-06-30'
group by
 p.name,
 grp.name,
 r.type,
 r.hours
```

Comment: I think there is a dicrepancy in test data here and on your test system. Check the screeshot I added to my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understood the question, all you need is to show for how many hours a user rented something divided by user's statuses (free, VIP, VIP+)

If so, you're almost there. I believe the problem is in "r.date between" condition.

when I changed it to

```
and r.date between h.date_from and h.date_to
```

the query gave me answer which seems to be correct.

PS. Not sure if you need to use left join here. As far as I can understand the logic, I think a regular join suits better

UPD: would this help?

```
SELECT p.name, 
       h.group_name, 
       sum(case when r.type = '10' then r.hours else 0 end) 
  FROM client p 
  left join history h
    on h.user_cid = p.c_id
  join rent r 
    on r.owner_id = p.c_id
   and r.date between h.date_from and h.date_to
 where p.c_id = 'poa'
   and r.date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-06-30'
 group by p.name, h.group_name
```

UPD2: Are you sure you have tested on same data as in the question? On my test system it gave exactly result you needed

[image: result]

UPD3: here, check the result with some additional test data
Note for simplicity reason I have commented date limitation clause

[image: result with additional data]

Comment: I tried this, but this solution doesn't handle the default date `2000-01-01` and `2099-12-31`. It gives me the values between those 2 dates and not between the given period which is `2021-01-01` and `2021-06-30`

Comment: I need to show for how many hours a user rented something when he was a free user (start period to end statut) and then when he was a VIP user (end previous statut to end period), etc. (this case there's only 2 date but it can be case where the user was a free user then a vip then a vip +, etc.)

Comment: I've added the SQL query with an additional where-contition. Try that one  please

Comment: I edited my question ! The result is close to the one desired

Comment: My dataset isn't exactly the same. I've simplified some table. I'm gonna check, but yes apparently it is what I want to do ! Can you please show me a screen with more than 2 group ? (Add a rent of 2 hours (type 10) when Paul is a VIP+ member and change the end period so we can have 3 rows)

Comment: @LouisChopard check the update please

Comment: Ok ! Can you just show me the output of this query ? As you did in the second screen.

Comment: @LouisChopard sorry, that was wrong screenshot. See the updated screenshot please

Comment: Ok so I checked my solution and tested it with different groups and it only get the values for one group and not the others. I think I'm doing something wrong with my join

Comment: Looks like you've over simplified the test data. I can only help if you posted some real data sample.

Comment: I updated my question with the (almost) full dataset.

Comment: @LouisChopard not sure if I can get back to you today. I'll check tomorrow whether you've got any answer and will try again if not

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need an interval check on the `history` table,  then simply add the `group` to the `group by` clause

```sql
SELECT
  p.name,
  h.[group],
  [Rent (1 day)] = SUM(CASE WHEN r.type = '10' THEN r.hours END) 
FROM client c 
JOIN history h ON h.user_cid = c.c_id
LEFT JOIN rent r ON r.owner_id = c.c_id
  AND r.date >= h.[from] AND r.date <= h.to
WHERE c.c_id = 'poa'
GROUP BY
  c.name,
  h.[group];
```

Notes:

- Better not to use reserver keywords such as `from` or `group` as object or column names
- A history table should ideally not even have an end time, just calculate the end time by referring to the next row.
- If the dates have time componenets then you need a half-open interval `r.date >= h.[from] AND r.date < h.to`